# How to place a image in the half of a frame using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to place a image in the half of a frame in my app , i am using xamarin forms to do this ,How can I do this

My Xaml

```
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
        <ListView x:Name="lv_search" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="175" SeparatorColor="White">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                            <Frame BackgroundColor = "White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="20,10,0,0"
                             HeightRequest="75" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.01,0.9,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                <Image Source = "img_frm" BackgroundColor="#14559a" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.009,0.9,0.3,0.6" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  />
                                <StackLayout Orientation = "Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" >
                                        <Image Source="ellipse_1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.01,0.4,1,1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                                        <Image Source = "{Binding Image}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.02,0.4,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  ></Image>
                                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                                    <Label x:Name="lbl_categories" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                      TextColor="Black"   Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                      FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.3,0.3,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
                                    <Image HorizontalOptions = "EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="arrow"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9,0.3,0.3,0.3"
                                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

But it dosen't develop the design what I want.

Actually I want a design like this

[image]

But I get the design like this,how to modify the design into the above image

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you try to explain it more? And show a screenshot of your (wrong) outcome?

Comment: @DennisSchröer I updated my question ,could you please help me.

Comment: Do you mean to control the size  of the image so it takes only 50% of the height of the `Frame`?

Comment: @DennisSchröer  I want to replace the square shaped blue image into the half of the frame as shown as the first design,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say this, but for the result you want to achieve, your xaml is a nightmare. Not only because you are having an excessive amount of elements in your visual tree, but also because you are using AbsoluteLayout inside a ListView.

Even though this is technically possible, it will cause your app losing performance, especially if your ListView gets populated with a lot of items.

Second, creating an image for that blue square also is a waste of memory and will cause more performance drops and ultimately probably OutOfMemoryExceptions on Android if your ListView contains many entries.

You could replace this with a custom View inheriting from a box view and using custom renderers for rendering rounded corners.

Also avoid using a StackLayout within a ListView, as it will also cause performance issues, since the StackLayout does a lot of calculations when being layouted.

As Dennis already mentioned, your way to go is using a Grid for layouting with keeping in mind, that all elements added to the grid will overlay each other in the order of how they have been added within your xaml definition.

Especially when using ListViews, try to use as less elements as possible and avoid elements which need a lot of layout passes.

Even though I am not using it in my example, I'd like to add the information, that you can also use negative margin values for advanced element positioning.

Here is a brief example, I hacked together:

```
<ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="80">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <!-- quick hack to make the list view populate items without having to write model classes -->
                <x:String>Entry 1</x:String>
                <x:String>Entry 2</x:String>
                <x:String>Entry 3</x:String>
                <x:String>Entry 4</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGray" Margin="19,9,9,9" />
                        <Grid Margin="20,10,10,10" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="18" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                            <!-- insert icons, labels, etc here -->
                        </Grid>
                        <customs:RoundedBoxView BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" CornerRadius="6" WidthRequest="15" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10,20,0,20" />
                </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The RoundedBoxView class looks like this:

```
public class RoundedBoxView : BoxView
{
    readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CornerRadius", typeof(double), typeof(double), 0.0);

    public double CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This would be the custom renderer for android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RoundedBoxView), typeof(RoundedBoxViewRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.Droid
{
public class RoundedBoxViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
{
    public RoundedBoxViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        SetWillNotDraw(false);
        Invalidate();
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        var box = Element as RoundedBoxView;
        var rect = new Rect();
        var paint = new Paint()
        {
            Color = box.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid(),
            AntiAlias = true,
        };
        GetDrawingRect(rect);
        var radius = (float)(box.CornerRadius); 
        canvas.DrawRoundRect(new RectF(rect), radius, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

And for iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RoundedBoxView), typeof(RoundedBoxViewRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.iOS
{
public class RoundedBoxViewRenderer: BoxRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Element != null)
        {
            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            UpdateCornerRadius(e.NewElement as RoundedBoxView);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == CircleView.WidthProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == CircleView.HeightProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateCornerRadius(Element as RoundedBoxView);
        }
    }

    void UpdateCornerRadius(RoundedBoxView box)
    {
        Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)(box.CornerRadius);

        CGRect bounds = new CGRect(0, 0, box.Width, box.Width);
        Layer.Bounds = bounds;
        Layer.Frame = bounds;
    }
}
```

Which will render like this:

[image]}

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Grid` instead of `AbsoluteLayout`.

I didn't test this, but try something like this:

```
<Grid 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Frame 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="White" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
        Margin="20,10,0,0"
        HeightRequest="75">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="ellipse_1" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                HeightRequest="100" 
                WidthRequest="100" 
                BackgroundColor="White">
            </Image>
            <Image 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Source="{Binding Image}" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            </Image>
            <Label 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                x:Name="lbl_categories" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                TextColor="Black"
                Text="{Binding Title}" 
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                FontSize="Medium" 
                FontAttributes="Bold">
            </Label>
            <Image 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="3" 
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                Source="arrow">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <Image 
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Source="img_frm" 
        BackgroundColor="#14559a">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Because the `Image` is created after the `Frame` in your xaml, it overlaps the `Frame`. You may need to change the margins of the `Frame` and blue square shaped `Image` according to your needs.

Comment: I tried this ,but the frame hides half of the image,I want the image above the frame